# Docker run command overhead

Tags: docker

I'm curious about the amount of overhead (time taken to start running, assuming I've already pulled the docker image) Docker gives when doing a `docker run` opposed to me just writing a script that installs the same things that the docker would. From my experience, `docker run` seems to always execute instantly and is ready to go, but I could imagine some more complicated dockers might have some additional overhead? I'm thinking about using something like YARN to bring up services on the fly with a docker, but was wondering if it might come up quicker without a Docker. Any thoughts on this?

Note: I'm not concerned about performance after the docker is up right now, I'm concerned about time taking to bring up the service.

Comment: As an example, my docker run of Captvty (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/k3ck3c/captvty/) needs 2 to 3 seconds to launch this Windows .exe + wine +various stuff, as it needs if I launch it directly from Linux

Comment: docker `run` command is almost instant, it's the image itself that slows it down a bit, depending on what's inside. Usually it takes 500ms up to 2 sec to cold start up a container (without the actual processes going inside of it). If you are worried about that marginal performance then I would suggest using some load balancing solution to mitigate the not ready container state.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is pretty quick to start, but there is some things to consider.

The quickest way to test the overhead is using the `time` executable and running this command:

```
docker run --rm -it ubunbu /bin/bash echo test
```

Which gives you something like this:

```
$ time docker run --rm -it ubuntu echo test
test

real    0m0.936s
user    0m0.161s
sys 0m0.008s
```

What you can read from this, is that the cpu only took 0.16 sec to run that command, but it took a little less than a sec in real time, which includes (disk I/O, other process)

But in general, do not worry about performance if you are using containers, they main reason you want to use them for is consistency.

Comment: Ubunbu. I laughed.